# HIVEQL, COUNT AMOUNT OF RECORDS PER DAY

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a database in hive that is in this structure:

```
+--------+------------------+---------+
| rating |      date        | version |
+--------+------------------+---------+
| 3      | 2021-07-01 12:13 | 2.1.9   |
| 5      | 2021-07-01 10:39 | 2.2.6   |
| 4      | 2021-07-02 10:24 | 2.2.7   |
| 5      | 2021-07-02 05:37 | 3.2.4   |
| 1      | 2021-07-02 21:40 | 3.2.5   |
```

How do I get the number of records per day and month with HiveQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count per day:

```
select substr(`date`,1,10) as `day`,
       count(*) cnt 
  from table_name 
 group by substr(`date`,1,10);
```

Monthly:

```
select substr(`date`,1,7) as `month`,
       count(*) cnt 
  from table_name 
 group by substr(`date`,1,7);
```